# Angular 2 routes not working after building the project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

These are my routes:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {WelcomeComponent} from "./welcome/welcome.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: WelcomeComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '**', component: WelcomeComponent}
];
```

I buid my project using `ng buid`.

When I enter a not defined path, I expect the application to redirect to `'/'` path as it happens during development, but I get an 404 Error.

I get the same error even when I manually enter /login URL.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide your module definition ?

Comment: how do you serve it after you built it ?

Comment: I move the folder dist generated after building the project to htdocs. Then open the project from browser

Comment: What exactly happens instead? Do you get a 404?

Comment: @not2savvy yes i get an 404 Error

Comment: Sounds like Milad's answer should help you, doesn't it?

Comment: @notsavvy I updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure if you're serving your app via a express server or any other web server , you should redirect all the get requests to `index.html`.

As long as your server is not redirecting all the requests to `index.html`, it doesn't matter what's happening inside your Angular app.

Comment: I am serving my app via Apache server, How should I redirect my get request to `index.html`? I will update my question adding the `.htaccess` file that i am using

Comment: @Milad Where this .htaccess file should be used, client side or backend side or any other location?

Answer (score 8):

As @Milad stated I had to redirect all get request to index.html.
Adding `.htacces` file solved my issue:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just note to those using local apache or xampp running PHP Application,  when adding .htacess  you might need to change index.html into your index.php  if that is what prints your angular app root tag  :<app-root></app-root>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect, you should specify exactly that:

```
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
```

However, I recommend something like:

```
  {path: '/welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/welcome'}
```

Also note the leading slashes in the path.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was fixed when I changed the build command from `ng build` to `ng build --prod`. Ofcourse you cannot use this solution when you need the build to function outside of the production environment.